# Посоветуйте такой слайдер/карусель jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider, carousel

Знает ли кто-нибудь на примете такой слайдер, чтоб можно было задавать количество дивов для одного слайда?
Подробнее: есть к примеру такая разметка

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>        
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
</div>
```

и нужно чтоб у одного слайда (одной прокрутки) было 2 item'а. В итоге будет 3 прокрутки, а не 6.
Также чтоб можно было этим управлять на разных разрешениях. К примеру на мобильниках уже нужно будет задать по одному item в слайде и будет 6 слайдов соответственно.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: slick slider - не благодарите

Comment: такой слайдер знаю. А как опция называется?

Comment: вы не поняли мой вопрос. Речь идет о том, чтоб в одном слайде было 2 item, в одном диве

Comment: расположите для блока в одном item

Comment: а как потом на мобильной сделать по одному??

Comment: Нужно чтоб один каждый слайд был отдельным дивом. А в настройках уже определять сколько item помещать в каждый div

Comment: в slick просто в ряд идут все слайды друг за другом. Они не группируются

Comment: [вот так примерно](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GwpMQy)

Comment: вы читали что я писал? как потом на мобильной можно будет задать чтоб было по одному? а так суть верна

Comment: или вертикально их расположить

Comment: дело в том что они когда 2, то друг под другом должны быть (item'ы в диве). Именно для этого мне нужен отдельный див для item'ов. Если можно их расположить не в ряд, а друг под другом, то так тоже устроит

Comment: Вот, нашлось вроде решение https://codepen.io/Kibs/pen/aNzvBG

Comment: ссылку мою посмотрите ещё раз

Comment: посмотрел, только вы тоже почитайте мои сообщения. Мне нужно было в отдельном диве каждый слайд

Comment: там и так каждый слайд по отдельности

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет [owl-carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html). Количество элементов легко регулируется для разных разрешениях параметром `responsive`:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть, например, **lightSlider**.
У него есть такая возможность.

```js
$('#autoplay').lightSlider({
  auto: false,
  loop: true,
  item: 2,
  slideMargin: 20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/src/css/lightslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/src/js/lightslider.js"></script>

<ul id="autoplay">
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/215x215?text=Slide 6" />
  </li>
</ul>
```